# Sending SCROLLTOP javascript via Submit

Tags: php, javascript, submit, scrolltop

I'm trying to submit a form after updating the value of a hidden field from a javascript variable.

This is the code:

```
<form name=form1 id=form1 method=get action=gestionale.php>
...
...
<input type=hidden name=scrolltop id=scrolltop value=''>
<input type=button name=update value=Update onClick=vai('form1');>
</form>

<script> 
function vai(formid) {
    document.getElementById('scrolltop').value=document.getElementById('offerte').scrollTop;
    document.getElementById(formid).submit();
}
</script>
```

The form submit works correctly but $_GET[scrolltop] after form submission, is empty even if it was filled with javascript. And testing it with alert before submit shows the correct value.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

```
function submit_form(formid) {
 var hidden = document.createElement("input");
 hidden.type = "hidden";
 hidden.name = "theName";
 hidden.value = document.getElementById('offerte').scrollTop;
 var f = document.getElementById("form2");
 f.appendChild(hidden);
 f.submit();
}
```

I submit the form using a javascript function instead of submit button.
Here I can set a hidden filed to a value I need in my action page.

Answer (score 0):

In your script...

The line `document.getElementById('scrolltop').value = document.getElementById('offerte').scrollTop;`

What exactly do you intend to do with the last bit (('offerte').scrollTop)?

As far as I understand, you want to return a text value, however setting the value to this will not return anything.

You will need to parse the query string ($_GET variable) and assign that to a variable which you will then pass as the value for the hidden field.

If I'm being completely in the dark here, I'm sorry. You should include a bit more of your code or additional information if my answer seems far fetched.

Anyway, I hope this helps!

Comment: I need to assign this value     (document.getElementById('offerte').scrollTop;) to a hidden field     <input type=hidden name=scrolltop id=scrolltop value=''>. I have to check the property scrollTop of element with ID 'offerte', that is a <DIV> element, when I click on the submit button. I do not have this value in my query string in that moment. Thanks for your help.